# phpmyadmin not getting connected when firstly open phpmyadmin after installing xampp in ubuntu

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with this error.

[image]

How can I open phpmyadmin?

Comment: Screenshots of your error are not helpful. Please include relevant information within your question if you would like people to try to help you.

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **Unfortunately, we can’t run your screenshot as code.**